# What does "admit until date" on I-94 mean?

Tags: usa, canada, tourist-visas

What does "admit until date" mean? Does that mean I have to leave by that day or I get in trouble?

Answer (score 9):

Yes. The Admit Until Date is the date that the traveler’s immigration status in the US expires.

Source: [CBP fact sheet I-94 expiration dates](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/502386%20-%20I-94%20Fact%20Sheet_OFO.pdf)